# Is there a way to check whether LittleSnitch is sending my private data to some bad dude?

Tags: mac, security

I installed LittleSnitch on my Mac to monitor my network activity.

But now I'm worried that maybe LittleSnitch itself is sending my data to some bad dude.

Is there another program I could install to monitor LittleSnitch and make sure it's only doing what it's supposed to do?

Comment: Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use [Network Monitor Sidekick](http://homepage.mac.com/rominar/net.html) to check on outbound and inbound traffic. Essentially, whatever goes out is allowed by LittleSnitch. Identifying the nature of the data and resolving the destination IP addresses is another matter altogether.

However, I would just like to add this: If you are really worried LittleSnitch has been corrupted, etc, why not just delete the app, along with its preferences, etc, and re-download and install [fresh from the web](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/) itself?

Answer (score 5):

try the famous [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) network sniffer, then you will see whats flying thru your fibers...

Comment: Great idea. If that's not good enough, build a tap cable, buy a network tap, or see if your switch already has built-in monitoring features (on many managed switches, you can designate one port to monitor another) — then run Wireshark on another computer.

Comment: Isn't this a bit too much?

Comment: @alex: depends on individual judgment of risks involved. BTW, I wouldn't run wireshark on the computer that is thought to run malware. A simple linux box router with two ethernet cards would be more trustworthy way to diagnose this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Let me mention that even Little Snitch (or your firewall program) is not capable of faking a server for HTTPS connections (because your browser or OCSP has the certain chain). So whatever data they could manage to send to a bad dude are useless even, because the bad dude doesn't have the server certificate.

This leads to my next question, which is: can a Firefox extension make fake certificates show up as good? I doubt it. But a hacked firefox... hmmm... that could be a worry-point.

Anyway, of course the answer is a network sniffer, but it'd have to be on another computer to be sure that the bad dudes at Little Snitch (ironically, the only software a software pirate actually has to buy) haven't thought about your sniffer too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NetBarrier](http://www.intego.com/netbarrier/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to monitor network activity and block certain applications.

For what it's worth, I use Little Snitch and have had no problems with it. I don't think it's sending data to other people.

Answer (score 0):

If it were doing anything bad don't you think it would have been outed by someone after all these years on the market?