# Is it possible to check whether a Mac is running keylogging software?

Tags: mac, security

I'm concerned that a program installed on my Mac (LittleSnitch) may be logging keystrokes and transmitting them to a remote host.

Ironically LittleSnitch is supposed to prevent other programs from doing this.

Is there any software for the Mac that would help me to verify this?

Comment: Is this the same as this question? http://superuser.com/questions/50475/

Comment: No, that question was asking whether there is a way to monitor LittleSnitch itself. This question is about how to investigate whether the computer is infected with a keylogger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire up [**WireShark**](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) and look for unusual network traffic periodically. Most keyloggers don't transmit logged keys on every keypress, negotiating all of those connections wouldn't be the best idea. Instead, keylogging software usually logs to a file for a specified amount of time **or** until the logfile reaches a certain size.

Comment: Figuring out which IP destinations are legitimate and which are not is what I'm not sure about.

Comment: @Karl: You can use sites such as http://dnsstuff.com to find out the locations of IPs.

Comment: @Chealion: Geographic locations? How would that help me determine if the IP destination of the network activity is legitimate or not? I don't believe a particular geographic location would provide any clues as to the legitimacy of the type of network activity being directed there.

Comment: You can do a reverse DNS lookup: http://remote.12dt.com/

Comment: @Karl: It's not perfect but knowing that your request is supposed to go to their data centre and that IP coincides with their whois records? Anything more than that and you may as well just nuke and pave because it's not worth the effort.

Comment: @John T & @Chealion: I see what you mean now! Wireshark in combination with reverse dns is a killer combination. My initial capture in WireShark showed that I'm only communicating with apple.com and other machines inside my network. To be on the safe side, I'm going to let WireShark continue capturing for another 24-48 hours to make sure. Thanks for the advice!